# Is there any performance issue on loading big component using this.props.children in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming, react-component

I am new to react native and I want to know that, Is there any performance issue when we load big component using `props.children` ?

For example I have below component :

**SafeScrollView.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform } from 'react-native';

const SafeScrollView = (props) => {
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        return (
          <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center'}}>
            {props.children}          
          </View>
        );
    }
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center'}} behavior="padding">
          {props.children}  
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
}

export default SafeScrollView
```

Now, I want to use this component in my signup screen which contains another lots of components like Image, TextInput, Button etc. Means whole SignUp screen will load in this `SafeScrollView` component. So will it create any performance issue in upcoming time?

Comment: Basic components shouldn't cause any performance issues. Anyway as soon as you pass images or animated components to your SafeScrollView.js there may occur performance issue. Then you would have to treat rendering to not render all components at once somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Depends on how much complex your logic is, which you have used inside the children component. But for basic screens with less animation and graphic use would not effect performance.